# What is a .running file?

Tags: eclipse, file

I am copying a decent amount of files - mostly Eclipse projects - and I got an error telling me a .running file could not be found.

**What is a .running file, and what is it used for?**

Comment: Maybe something similar to this: `Please not that, while the program is running, it will incrementally output the results in a file that has the path and name that you specified but with a .running extension. For example, if you specified out.properties as the output file then the running file would be out.properties.running.`, from http://web.stanford.edu/~horridge/publications/2014/iswc/atomic-decomposition/data/

Comment: Good info! This file was just named `.running` though. Maybe it's some sort of library thing?

Comment: As the quote says, I think it is a generated file used while your program is running. I'm surprised there's so little information about it.

Comment: `After completion, one should check for the presence of .failed and .running files. A leftover .running means that the CIVET run is incomplete, likely due to some unexpected interruption (power failure?)`, from here http://www.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/ServicesSoftware/OutputsOfCIVET  Seems like it is supposed to be destroyed automatically if your program closes properly as well.